# I am trying to add an extra textbox row on current textbox being clicked how do i do it

Tags: javascript, html, textbox, onchange

the current code given below is adding textbox but empyting contents of current textbox
Adding extra text row on current row being changed. I am trying to add a hashtagging system like iphone tags in html. how do i do this?

```
  <div style="padding:15px;border-bottom:solid 1px #c0bbbb;background:#f3f0f0;border-left:solid 1px #c0bbbb;border-right:solid 1px #c0bbbb;">
  <fieldset>
  <form method="POST" id="hashform" name="hashform" action="/addtags">
<p><input type='text' onchange='generateRow();return false;' name='hashtags[]'></p>
    <div id="tags"></div>
    <br><br>
<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Add HashTags" />

  </form>
  </fieldset>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  try{document.hashform.hashtag.focus();}
        catch(ex){}
 function generateRow() {
    var d=document.getElementById("tags");
    d.innerHTML+="<p><input type='text'  onchange='generateRow();return false;' name='hashtags[]'></p>";
    }
    generateRow();

  </script>
```

Comment: Could any one explain/edit this question? Adding either a row or a textBox is very simple but where and when to add? I have been unable to get it from question and code

Comment: Where is the value field for input which will restore the text inserted?